# laravel 4 - add record to new user after registeration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, registration

i want to add record to a new user right after regeneration complete the problem that i get the user->id with null value  after calling user->save() .

Here is my code

```
public function register(){

    $input=Input::all();

    $rules=array(
        'username'=>'required|unique:bradoseusers|alphaNum|min:2',
        'email'=> 'required|unique:bradoseusers|email',
        'password'=>'required|alphaNum|min:6'
    );

    $v=Validator::make($input,$rules);

    if($v->passes())
    {   

        $password=$input['password'];
        $password=Hash::make($password);
        $user=new Bradoseusers();
        $user->username=$input['username'];
        $user->Email=$input['email'];
        $user->password=$password;
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/Register')->withErrors($v);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have your database set to auto increment for the id column?

Comment: Also, this $user=new Bradoseusers(); should just be $user=new Bradoseusers;

Comment: i have made your changes and the user->id still with null value

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $input=Input::all();
    $rules=array(...);
    $v = Validator::make($input,$rules);

    if($v->passes()) {   
        $user = new Bradoseusers;
        $user->username = $input['username'];
        $user->Email = $input['email'];
        $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user->save();
        // probably you want to redirect to
        // default landing page for logged in user
        return Redirect::to('login'); // i.e /dashboard or /
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to('/Register')->withErrors($v)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i  have  set in the model  the primaryKey property to "Email" . So that would override the primary key value so you wouldn't have an "id" field.